# Library for remote file access in linux?

Tags: linux, file, remote-access

Im working on a program to access files from remote hosts. Basically what i want to do is logging in remote Windows/Linux host with valid credentials, check what files exist in a specific folder, read those files.
Is there a library I can use to fulfill the above purpose in Linux?

Thanks.

Additional info:
I'm using C. The remote hosts are not expected to have any non-default service (say ftp) running on them. So as long as the protocol can support most default-config-hosts, it should be fine.

Thanks again.

Comment: We need more information. What language are you using and what sort of protocol do you want to use? FTP, NFS, CIFS, etc etc?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need an api like [libssh](http://www.libssh.org) ...

> The ssh library was designed to be
>   used by programmers needing a working
>   SSH implementation by the mean of a
>   library. The complete control of the
>   client is made by the programmer. With
>   libssh, you can remotely execute
>   programs, transfer files, use a secure
>   and transparent tunnel for your remote
>   programs.

Answer (score 0):

[gio](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/) can handle any protocol that has a plugin, but you'll need to use [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) in order to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

To really simplify your programming task, use a fuse module to map the remote
system to a local filesystem and just access it with filesystem semantics. ;)
http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html